# Outlook VBA: Why does Sender and ReceivedByName return the same name?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I wrote a mail saver macro that reads the recipient, sender and some other stuff, formats the file name and saves as *.msg. This works fine from the inbox. However when I use it from my "sent" folder, the below code bit returns my name as both the sender and recipient. Why is that?

The basic mail format looks like this:

Inbox folders:
- Sender (someone) 
- Subject
- Recipient (me)

Sent folders:
- Sender (me)
- Subject 
- Recipient (someone)

Code:

```
For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Set oMail = objItem

        mSender = oMail.Sender
        'mSender = oMail.SenderName 'Same result as .Sender

        mRecipient = oMail.ReceivedByName
        'mRecipient = oMail.ReceivedOnBehalfOfName   'Same result as .ReceivedByName

        MsgBox "Sender: " & mSender & "_ Recipient: " & mRecipient
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it's

```
oMail.Recipients.Item(i)
```